# AWS S3 Metadata iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I am developing photo sharing application in iOS using Amazon as backend.
I have uploaded photo to S3 but my problem is how to get metadata of uploaded photo, actually i want lat and lang of that photo. I am using latest sdk version 2.0.2 of aws.
Can you help me? Can you guid me which function I have to use to get meta data information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location data, if available, is embedded inside the image file itself and is not part of the file's S3 object metadata. You can define your own [custom metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) when the image is uploaded and set the image's coordinates there.

It may be better though to store the coordinates in a DynamoDB table along with the image's S3 object key to provide better lookup and querying.